# How to render formio custom form component into our application using angular

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

While executing this code  i am getting [---- Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?, ?, ?)   ----] this type of error

I am trying to render formio password component to my application.
For that i creted a class called AppComponent

The following code as...

```html
<app-root></app-root>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormioResources } from 'angular-formio/resource';
import { FormioAuthService } from 'angular-formio/auth';
import { AppConfig } from '../config';
import { FormioForm } from 'formiojs/full';
//import from './components/CheckMatrix';
import TextFieldComponent from 'formiojs/components/textfield/TextField';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent extends TextFieldComponent {
  static schema(...extend) {
    return TextFieldComponent.schema({
      type: 'password',
      label: 'Password',
      key: 'password'
    }, ...extend);
  }

  static get builderInfo() {
    return {
      title: 'Password',
      icon: 'fa fa-asterisk',
      group: 'basic',
      documentation: 'http://help.form.io/userguide/#password',
      weight: 20,
      schema: AppComponent.schema()
    };
  }

  get defaultSchema() {
    return AppComponent.schema();
  }

  elementInfo() {
    const info = super.elementInfo();
    info.attr.type = 'password';
    return info;
  }
}
```